# Cakephp 3 Side Navigation resize

Tags: css, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to change the layout so the side navigation is smaller which i have done by editing the cake.css

```
.top-bar.expanded .title-area {
    background: #01545b;
    width:350px;
}
#actions-sidebar {
    background: #fafafa;
    width:350px;
}
```

However the main content has not moved across not sure what i need to edit for it to align correctly

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Add a local.css file and add this. Set the percentages to your liking, but make sure they add up to 100%.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.0625em) {
    .large-3 {
        width: 15%;
    }
    .large-9 {
        width: 85%;
    }
}
```

Or you could create a theme. See this post: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/themes-in-cakephp-3-howto/